# postgres columns attribute for json

Tags: json, postgresql, nginx

I am currently a happy user of [ngx_postgres](https://github.com/FRiCKLE/ngx_postgres/). However I recently discover I need to do something very weird. Basically I need to produce the following json output:

```
{
     "PatientName": {
         "Tag": "00100010",
         "VR": "PN",
         "PersonName": [
           {
             "SingleByte": "Wang^XiaoDong",
             "Ideographic": "王^小東"
           }
         ]
     },
},
{
     "PatientName": {
         "Tag": "00100010",
         "VR": "PN",
         "PersonName": [
           {
             "SingleByte": "John^Doe",
           }
         ]
     },
}
```

With a little reading of the DICOM standard it is easy to create (simplified) a table of equivalent for Keyword, Tag and VR:

```
CREATE TABLE equiv (
    "Keyword" varchar(64) PRIMARY KEY,
    "Tag" char(8) NOT NULL,
    "VR" char(2) NOT NULL,
);
```

Well now the tricky part is this indirection with PatientName that I do not understand, I tried:

```
CREATE TABLE patientname (
    "SingleByte" varchar(64) primary key,
    "Ideographic" varchar(64),
);
CREATE TABLE patientlevel_impl_detail (
    "PatientName" varchar(64) references patientname("SingleByte"),
    "PatientID" character varying(64) NOT NULL
);
CREATE view patientlist as select
patientname."SingleByte",
patientname."Ideographic",
patientname."Phonetic",
patientlevel_impl_detail."PatientID"
FROM patientlevel_impl_detail,patientname where patientlevel_impl_detail."PatientName" = patientname."SingleByte";
```

However in any case a TABLE and/or a VIEW is always flatten, and instead I am getting something like:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/patients
[
     {
         "Tag": "00100010",
         "VR": "PN",
         "SingleByte": "John^Doe",
         "Ideographic": null,
     },
]
```

So I do not see how I can make PersonName an array of nested string (nested json tree).

Note: I am not using 9.3, I need to use 9.1 for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 9.1, do yourself a favor and get the [json extension](http://people.planetpostgresql.org/andrew/index.php?/archives/255-JSON-for-PG-9.2-...-and-now-for-9.1!.html) for 9.1.  It will save you a lot of work.

The second thing you need to do is to create a nested data structure as a view which matches your json structure.  You will use array_agg() for this:

```
CREATE view patientlist as select
arrayagg(patientname) as "PatientName"
patientlevel_impl_detail."PatientID"
FROM patientlevel_impl_detail,patientname 
where patientlevel_impl_detail."PatientName" = patientname."SingleByte";
```

Then you should be able to:

```
SELECT row_to_json(patientlist) FROM patientlist;
```